# Display vector images in iOS (SVG or FXG)

Tags: objective-c, ios, svg, fxg

I would like to display images in Adobe FXG file format (exported from flash) or SVG format in an iOS application.
Is there an Objective-C tool or library that can render vector graphics ?

*(I don't want to convert my images to bitmap format ! I would like to keep vector format)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

maybe [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) could help:

> SVGKit is a cross-platform Cocoa framework for rendering SVG files as Core Animation layers. All shapes are represented by instances of the CAShapeLayer class, and are, by design, animatable. SVGKit is compatible with the latest OS X and iOS SDK's.

**Note**: Nowadays i would recommend to use [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com) instead!

Answer (score 1):

An old question for sure, but hopefully this new answer may help things out.  I've spent the weekend looking for a solution, but I wanted to avoid using parsers.  I did find a program called [Qwarkee](http://wavecoders.ca/productsDefault.cfm?prod=2) which converts svg code into Quartz2D calls.  Unfortunately, it's a paid app.  (FYI, I have no relation with the project).

If you are looking to produce your artwork specifically for iOS, there are programs like Opacity and PaintCode that will produce the Quartz as you draw your image.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Dont do this. Apples raw calls are SLOWER than using a parser, by a long way. There are no advantages, only disadvantages. I'm one of the contributors to SVGKit, but i tried Apple native calls first, and found out the hard way: they suck.

Comment: SVGKit uses the same drawing after parsing, isn't it?

Comment: Native Core graphics calls are fine, and getting faster all the time. Maybe you found a dysfunctional case or some particular thing that is slow, like some ways you could measure text, but in general, CG is a solid API.