# Adaptive Layout Full Screen Image

Tags: ios, swift, adaptive-ui

Using Adaptive Layout, what is the best or recommended approach for displaying a full screen background image to ensure it works on all devices, both orientations?

Is it a case of making an image the largest possible size (iPad Pro) and then scaling down?

Also, how would you handle screen rotation? Manually detect this and rotate image?

Comment: Use a large one? iPad Pro is 2732x2048, so using that size would work on all devices (I would personally use `Aspect Fit`). Of course, your best shot is to use vectorial images, so they scale nicely to all screen sizes. Watch this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908374/display-vector-images-in-ios-svg-or-fxg